# Signed apk file crashes at the begining

Tags: android, constructor, crash, apk, accessible

The app work fine when i'm loading it from the Android Studio to my Nexus 5, but after I generated an apk file and install it on the device (after I uninstalled it) - it crashes when i'm trying to open the app.

ERROR from LogCat:

```
 --------- beginning of crash
09-10 18:14:37.976  18853-18853/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.eladblau.myfamily, PID: 18853
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eladblau.myfamily/com.example.eladblau.myfamily.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default constructor for class com.a.nj is not accessible.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default constructor for class com.a.nj is not accessible.
            at com.a.it.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.it.G(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.ek.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.eladblau.myfamily.m.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.eladblau.myfamily.m.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.eladblau.myfamily.m.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.eladblau.myfamily.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: You've tried to sign by other signature file? Where do you generate a signature storage?

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: I don't think the problem is signature realated, maybe a too aggressive proguard config?

Comment: Try to disable proguard and test

Comment: Make your constructor public

Comment: @Prabhuraj I have tried to make the constructor public but it's the same.